# Videostream from my website to youtube

Tags: video, youtube, stream

I need some info about:

1. Videostreaming to youtube (somebody can view my stream as video)
2. Sending screenshot of my div to videostream.
3. Anything connected with written above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link below i hope it helps:

http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/youtube.html